# Add image in Google Doc from Google Sheet via Script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-docs

There is an image in Google Sheet (coming from Google Form) that I would like to insert in Google Doc in **Image Format**. Currently, I'm getting Url only from the below mention script. How can I get the image. This is the script-

```
function afterFormSubmit(e) {
  const info = e.namedValues;
  createPDF (info);

}

function createPDF(info){
   
  const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1I7ChP1xRbl7GwnvAcXV_9JIHegvsU2PO");
  const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1srcXlFgmh01e4Psw_dxM4bNgarY6tfli");
  const templateDoc = DriveApp.getFileById("1xype5jUa6H8VJ4JSaV-KfccSjK5w6e-hmoI1k6MXSOc");

  const newTempFile = templateDoc.makeCopy(tempFolder);
  const openDoc =  DocumentApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());
  const body = openDoc.getBody();
  body.replaceText("{Location Code}",info['Location Code'][0]);
  body.replaceText(" {Timestamp}",info['Timestamp'][0]);
  body.replaceText( " {Upload Image}",info['Upload Image'][0]);
  
  openDoc.saveAndClose();

  const blobPDF = newTempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDF).setName(info['Location Code'][0]+"-"+new Date());
  tempFolder.removeFile(newTempFile);
  /** @type {any} */

}
```

[image: Google Doc Format]

[image: Currently getting data like this]

[image: Google sheet input sheet via Google Form]

Comment: Please show what you tried regarding inserting an image to a Google Doc and a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Related https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/148397/88163

Comment: @Rubén I am trying to insert an image(images are coming from Google Form-I have their link in google sheet-pic attached above) into a Google doc. I have {Upload image} text in the position where I want to insert the image(pic attached above. Currently, I'm using this(full script attached above)-   body.replaceText( " {Upload Image}",info['Upload Image'][0]); - As I'm new to this scripting I don't know what changes I need to do to get image from Url to Google doc

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add an image uploaded from a Google Form into a Google Document (via Google Spreadsheet) but only the image url is being inserted into the document.

To implement this answer, do the following:

1 - Establish the index number for the paragraph `{Upload Image}` in the Google Document.

2 - Replace `<indexnumber>` in the code below with the index number of the paragraph.

3 - Delete this line

```
body.replaceText( " {Upload Image}",info['Upload Image'][0]);
```

4 - Substitute these lines

```
body.replaceText("{Upload Image}", "");
// Convert image to blob
var myimage  = info['Upload Image'][0];
var fileID = myimage.match(/[\w\_\-]{25,}/).toString();
var blob   = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID).getBlob();
body.insertImage(<indexnumber>, blob);
```

---

There are two aspects to this answer:

1 - **body.replaceText( " {Upload Image}",info['Upload Image'][0]);**

This is literally replacing one piece of text `{Upload Image}` with a second piece of text (the document url); instead you need to delete `{Upload Image}`. This is the purpose of `body.replaceText("{Upload Image}", "");`

2 - **[body.insertImage()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body?hl=en#insertimagechildindex,-image)**

The image needs to be converted to a blob, and then inserted with `insertImage()`.

There are two arguments:

- the first is the `childIndex` for the position to insert the image; this is the purpose of establishing the index number for the paragraph `{Upload Image}`.
- the second is the blob.

---

**Document template**

[image: Merge document]

---

**PDF**

[image: PDF]

---

Credit: [Digital Inspirations](https://www.labnol.org/code/20078-insert-image-in-google-document) for the regex to return the file ID of the image.